# How to determine scene tile's x, y and z on tile server?

Tags: tiles, planet

At the core, I would like to get part of scene from planet labs tile server (png image). In short, what is the math between (long, lat) coordinate in EPSG:4326 to tile (x, y, z) values?

Planet Labs tile server url (needed values are marked in curly braces):

> /v0/scenes/ortho/20151104_205545_0c03/{Z}/{X}/{Y}.png?api_key=PL_API_KEY

Successful result would be something like this for coordinates (-111.872430526; 40.1277639813) [coordinates are approximate, not exact]:

> /v0/scenes/ortho/20151104_205545_0c03/16/10767/24780.png?api_key=PL_API_KEY

I have not been able to find specification for planet labs tile server (or of any other tile servers in fact).

I followed a [tutorial](https://www.planet.com/docs/v0/tutorials/ol3-scene-tiles.html#scene-tiles-in-ol3-map) where openlayers does exactly what is needed - requests parts of scene at given coordinates, generates (x, y, z) values returns png image.
And I am on to road of extracting needed part from the openlayers source, so at some near future point I will succeed.

Comment: Here https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile is a mapbox python API that seems to do what you want

Comment: @til_b, super big thanks. Link to this library was useful and function _tile()_ (https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile/blob/master/mercantile/__init__.py) was exactly what I needed .
Not only to go further without understanding... How is this transformation called?

Comment: I don't know a common name for the transformation operation, sorry.